# Creating KML that is synced to CartoDB data and styles?

Tags: google-earth, carto, kmz

The one part of CartoDB I am struggling with is connecting my table or visualization to Google earth. I see that you can export an un-styled KMZ from a table.

Has anyone figured out a way to keep a synced or network lined KMZ/KML file with polygons from a CartoDB table or visualization?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question well, you need to create a KML file, open it in Google Earth, and whenever the KML file is changed, the view in GE is uptaded.

For this, you need to load a KML file in GE with the following:

```
<NetworkLink>
    <Link>
        <href>C:/Users/User/Documents/my_file.kml</href>
        <refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode>
        <refreshInterval>2</refreshInterval>
    </Link>
</NetworkLink>
```

my_file.kml is obviously the file you want to visualize in GE.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with anyone doing it. I tried to figure out what options there were and one of the best would be to just visualize the tile layer on Google Earth. Buuuut, that is a challenge too. One way might be here,

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/regions#superoverlays

But I didn't see a clear path. Sorry :(